# Postgresql: handle all queries to change user's password?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have to log all such queries to my database on Amazon RDS
The best way, of course, create a trigger on pg_catalog.pg_authid, but I have no privileges to operate system catalog.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to set `log_statement = 'ddl'`. That will log other DDL statements as well.